# in Corona SDK will store.purchase() always timeout/return in all cases?

Tags: coronasdk

Will store.purchase() always timeout/return in all cases?

That is can I be confident that I can leave my modal dialog with a spinner in place waiting for a response back from this call?

(doesn't really say anything about this in the docs at http://docs.coronalabs.com/daily/api/library/store/purchase.html#store.purchase )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it does. When you initiate the store using `store.init( [storeName,] listener )` you specify the store name and a callback function for your transactions i.e. `store.init("apple", transactionCallback)`. In this callback function you can check for certain transaction states.

```
local function transactionCallback( event )
    local transaction = event.transaction
    print("EVENT:PHASE = " .. transaction.state)

    if transaction.state == "purchased" then
        print("Transaction succuessful!")
        print("productIdentifier", transaction.productIdentifier)
        print("receipt", transaction.receipt)
        print("signature", transaction.signature)
        print("transactionIdentifier", transaction.identifier)
        print("date", transaction.date)
    elseif  transaction.state == "restored" then
        print("Transaction restored (from previous session)")
        print("signature", transaction.signature)        
        print("productIdentifier", transaction.productIdentifier)
        print("receipt", transaction.receipt)
        print("transactionIdentifier", transaction.identifier)
        print("date", transaction.date)
        print("originalReceipt", transaction.originalReceipt)
        print("originalTransactionIdentifier", transaction.originalIdentifier)
        print("originalDate", transaction.originalDate)
    elseif transaction.state == "cancelled" then
        print("User cancelled transaction")
    elseif transaction.state == "failed" then
        print("Transaction failed, type:", transaction.errorType, transaction.errorString)
    else
        print("unknown event")
    end
end
```

Comment: actually I think the scenario I saw when it seems to lock up was one where my ADSL internet modem connection died during the purchase...make any sense...definitely got stuck and wasn't returning...

Comment: @Greg That makes sense. But it should timeout though. Did it?

Comment: @Eyeball It was taking over a minute, but I must admit I gave up after this.  Over a minute is too long.  Do you have a deployed app that makes the assumption that it will return?  Have you had any problems?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, but if it senses some kind of internet connection (even a bad one) it will keep the dialog up until it receives a response and considering players playing on mobile internet can very often have poor connectivity.  You might want to insert a Corona timer that cancels the process and notifies a user with a dialog if a response hasn't been received in a reasonable amount of time.